# JS How can I call a function within another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I'm not exactly sure how to word what I'm trying to do.

I'm using leaflet and a geosearch plugin (https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch/tree/master/src/js)

The search box is watching for an enter key to be pressed inside it, before it fires off the geosearch function.

I want to be able to call the geosearch function from another element (an `onClick()` event somewhere else on the page for example).

But I don't know how to target the `geosearch: function (qry)`, as it's inside another function - `L.Control.GeoSearch = L.Control.extend({})`

```
 /*
 * L.Control.GeoSearch - search for an address and zoom to its location
 * https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch
 */

L.GeoSearch = {};
L.GeoSearch.Provider = {};

L.GeoSearch.Result = function (x, y, label, bounds) {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
    this.Label = label;
    this.bounds = bounds;
};

L.Control.GeoSearch = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topcenter',
        showMarker: true,
        retainZoomLevel: false,
        draggable: false
    },

    _config: {
        country: 'nz',
        searchLabel: 'search for address ...',
        notFoundMessage: 'Sorry, that address could not be found.',
        messageHideDelay: 3000,
        zoomLevel: 13
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        L.Util.extend(this.options, options);
        L.Util.extend(this._config, options);
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        var $controlContainer = map._controlContainer,
            nodes = $controlContainer.childNodes,
            topCenter = false;

        for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
            var klass = nodes[i].className;
            if (/leaflet-top/.test(klass) && /leaflet-center/.test(klass)) {
                topCenter = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!topCenter) {
            var tc = document.createElement('div');
            tc.className += 'leaflet-top leaflet-center';
            $controlContainer.appendChild(tc);
            map._controlCorners.topcenter = tc;
        }

        this._map = map;
        this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-geosearch');

        var searchbox = document.createElement('input');
        searchbox.id = 'leaflet_control_geosearch_qry';
        searchbox.type = 'text';
        searchbox.placeholder = this._config.searchLabel;
        this._searchbox = searchbox;

        var msgbox = document.createElement('div');
        msgbox.id = 'leaflet-control-geosearch-msg';
        msgbox.className = 'leaflet-control-geosearch-msg';
        this._msgbox = msgbox;

        var resultslist = document.createElement('ul');
        resultslist.id = 'leaflet-control-geosearch-results';
        this._resultslist = resultslist;

        this._msgbox.appendChild(this._resultslist);
        this._container.appendChild(this._searchbox);
        this._container.appendChild(this._msgbox);

        L.DomEvent
          .addListener(this._container, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
          .addListener(this._searchbox, 'keypress', this._onKeyUp, this);

        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this._container);

        return this._container;
    },

    geosearch: function (qry) {
        var that = this;
        try {
            var provider = this._config.provider;

            if(typeof provider.GetLocations == 'function') {
                var results = provider.GetLocations(qry, function(results) {
                    that._processResults(results);
                });
            }
            else {
                var url = provider.GetServiceUrl(qry);
                this.sendRequest(provider, url);
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            this._printError(error);
        }
    },

    sendRequest: function (provider, url) {
        var that = this;

        window.parseLocation = function (response) {
            var results = provider.ParseJSON(response);
            that._processResults(results);

            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('getJsonP'));
            delete window.parseLocation;
        };

        function getJsonP (url) {
            url = url + '&callback=parseLocation';
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.id = 'getJsonP';
            script.src = url;
            script.async = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        if (XMLHttpRequest) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if ('withCredentials' in xhr) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xhr.status == 200) {
                            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText),
                                results = provider.ParseJSON(response);

                            that._processResults(results);
                        } else if (xhr.status == 0 || xhr.status == 400) {
                            getJsonP(url);
                        } else {
                            that._printError(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                };

                xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                xhr.send();
            } else if (XDomainRequest) {
                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();

                xdr.onerror = function (err) {
                    that._printError(err);
                };

                xdr.onload = function () {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText),
                        results = provider.ParseJSON(response);

                    that._processResults(results);
                };

                xdr.open('GET', url);
                xdr.send();
            } else {
                getJsonP(url);
            }
        }
    },

    _processResults: function(results) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
            this._map.fireEvent('geosearch_foundlocations', {Locations: results});
            this._showLocation(results[0]);
        } else {
            this._printError(this._config.notFoundMessage);
        }
    },

    _showLocation: function (location) {
        if (this.options.showMarker == true) {
            if (typeof this._positionMarker === 'undefined') {
                this._positionMarker = L.marker(
                    [location.Y, location.X],
                    {draggable: this.options.draggable}
                ).addTo(this._map);
            }
            else {
                this._positionMarker.setLatLng([location.Y, location.X]);
            }
        }
        if (!this.options.retainZoomLevel && location.bounds && location.bounds.isValid()) {
            this._map.fitBounds(location.bounds);
        }
        else {
            this._map.setView([location.Y, location.X], this._getZoomLevel(), false);
        }

        this._map.fireEvent('geosearch_showlocation', {
          Location: location,
          Marker : this._positionMarker
        });
    },

    _printError: function(message) {
        var elem = this._resultslist;
        elem.innerHTML = '<li>' + message + '</li>';
        elem.style.display = 'block';

        this._map.fireEvent('geosearch_error', {message: message});

        setTimeout(function () {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
        }, 3000);
    },

    _onKeyUp: function (e) {
        var esc = 27,
            enter = 13;

        if (e.keyCode === esc) { // escape key detection is unreliable
            this._searchbox.value = '';
            this._map._container.focus();
        } else if (e.keyCode === enter) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            this.geosearch(this._searchbox.value);
        }
    },

    _getZoomLevel: function() {
        if (! this.options.retainZoomLevel) {
            return this._config.zoomLevel;
        }
        return this._map.zoom;
    }

});
```

I've looked everywhere, but I guess I don't know what to call what I'm doing. I've even tried just setting `focus()` to the searchbox and sending an enter key, but that didn't work either (without a sendkey plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this to attach a click event to a button. When clicking the button the geoSearchController will query after "New York" but you can change that to work with any value you want.

```
// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.5, -0.5], 5);

// Set up tiles
L.tileLayer(
    'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
    {maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);

//Create and add the geoSearchController
var geoSearchController = new L.Control.GeoSearch({
    provider: new L.GeoSearch.Provider.Google()
}).addTo(map);

//Add a click handler to a button with the id myButton
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function(){     
    geoSearchController.geosearch('New York');
});
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/6s1np2n4/)

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. I'll attach this to my address autocomplete list, so when the user selects an address from the autocomplete, it will fire the search.

Answer (score 1):

Never used the plugin, but it looks like that L.Control.extend({...}) statement is adding all of those properties to L.Control, which would mean you could simply call `L.Control.geosearch()` directly (with your `qry` parameter, of course).

Something along the lines of:

`<button onclick="L.Control.geosearch('myquery')">Button</button>`

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but using L.Control.geosearch('myquery'), comes back with TypeError: L.Control.geosearch is not a function

Comment: No, it looks like I mislead you slightly. That `extend({})` statement is creating a _new_ extended copy of `L.Control` as `L.Control.GeoSearch`. So try calling `L.Control.GeoSearch.geosearch('myquery')`. You'll want to verify that you are not calling it until after it has been defined (which shouldn't be a problem if you're triggering it from a button). If that one works, I'll update my answer.